# What is the 'default' sort of Paging and Sorting Repository in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to understand Spring Data JPA paging.

How is the data sorted when I call any `findAll` with Paging only, without any Sorting.

Below I try to fetch the 1st Page(of size 100) from the repository. I want to know how the result I get is sorted without any implied sorting. Is this 'default' sorting dependent on the actual order of results received from the database.

```
        Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(1, 100);
        List<Citizen> citizens = citizenRepository.findAll(pageRequest).getContent();
```

Comment: "*Is this 'default' sorting dependent on the actual order of results received from the database*" yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass the sort object - then default database sorting is applied.
For some databases it's by primary key (ID) with ASC but this is not in ANSI specification so I wouldn't rely on this.